# Проблема с Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, исключения

Для парсинга json использую библиотеку Newtonsoft.Json, был рабочий код:

```
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(rawJson);
return json.services;
```

Все было ок, но вот на днях понадобилось доделать этот проект, добавил фичу, скомпилил, и вдруг получаю Exception в этом коде!

```
"Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject" не содержит определения для "services"
```

Использую MS VS 2012 Json.Net ставил через NuGet

P.S. находил похожую проблему на просторах интернета, помогло переустановка винды и студии, не хочю так, да и странно как то...

Answer (score 3):

Во первых, воспользуйтесь отладчиком, чтобы проверить что-же там есть внутри объекта json. Можно в Locals, QuickWatch или Watch посмотреть значение `json.ChildrenTokens` - там будет то, что действительно распарсилось.

Если services там нет, то есть два варианта:

- там есть что-то другое, и у вас все таки другой json
- у вас подгрузилась какая-то кривая версия json.net

Проверить можно на минимальном примере (который должен быть у вас в вопросе, раз вы просите помочь с отладкой):

```
string rawJson = "{ \"currentVersion\" : \"10.02\", \"folders\" : [ \"DAP\", \"DASP\" ], \"services\" : [ {\"name\" : \"AdmDelenie\", \"type\" : \"MapServer\"}, {\"name\" : \"Administr\", \"type\" : \"MapServer\"} ] }";

dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(rawJson);
var services = json.services;
```

Если этот пример работает - то у вас другой json. Этот вы привели в комментариях. Ищите разницу.

Если этот пример не работает - значит или у вас какая-то древняя битая версия json.net, или подгружется что-то кривое, напрмиер, не из папки bin, а из gac.

Проверить можно в окне Debug / Windows / Modules - найдите там newtownsoft.json и посмотрите откуда он загружен. Автор newtownsoft.json злоупотребляет релизом версий без увеличения assembly version, так что вполне возможно что у вас загружается что-то совсем не той версии (например, что-то древнее с багом в парсинге dynamic).

Кстати, в студии есть встроенный генератор классов из JSON: Edit/Paste special/JSON as Classes. Пользуйтесь ими вместо dynamic:

```
// переименовать в что-то более осмысленное
public class Rootobject
{
    public string currentVersion { get; set; }
    public string[] folders { get; set; }
    public Service[] services { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

Rootobject stronglyTyped = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(rawJson);
```

Answer (score 2):

Не хочу показаться кэпом, но наверно причина в том, что json объект не содержит свойства services. Вообще юзать dynamic не стоит, тормозная это штука, лучше парсить json в строго типизированный объект.

Comment: Да забыл указать, JSON коректный, вот его краткий вид:

    {"currentVersion" : "10.02", 
    "folders" : [
    "DAP", 
    "DASP"
    ], 
    "services" : [
     {"name" : "AdmDelenie", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "Administr", "type" : "MapServer"}
   ]
 }

Comment: P.S. насчет динамик, возможно откажусь, но перелопачивать существуающий проект ой как не хочеться...

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```
// Получаем JObject. 
public JObject GetJson()  
{
    var serializer = JsonSerializer();    

    // В качестве параметра конструктора, поток содержащий данные json.
    using(var sr = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream()))
    {
        using(var jtr = JsonTextReader(sr))
        {  
            string json = serializer.Deserialize(jtr).ToString(); 

            return JObject.Parse(json);
        }
    }       
}

// Получаем объект JObject.
var myObj = GetJson();

// Получаем значение.
var value = myObj["currentVersion"].ToString(); // 10.02
```